# Python/C++: Running .cpp in Python

Tags: python, c++

Total beginner here, so please be gentle. I have a example.cpp file which has one main function which accepts some input parameters and returns an integer value.

How would I run this .cpp file from within Python such that I can specify the input parameters from within Python and access the output of the .cpp so that it is stored in Python?

Thanks

I've modified the main function to accept command line input. What do you mean by "returns its result as its exit code", kindall?

Also, want to add that I'd want to return a vector created from the .cpp so that the variable is in Python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Comment: First, rewrite the C++ program so it accepts arguments on the command line and returns its result as its exit code. Then use Pythons `subprocess.call` to call it.

Comment: How do you build this .cpp file? Is it an executable, a library or shared library? Does the function have a complicated command signature? Is the function literally "main"? Is it the entry point of the program? Life would be a lot better if you gave an example like say `int foo() { return 1; }`.

Comment: @kindall good for very small ints only!

Comment: You have a main that is doing multiple things such as prompting the user for input and printing status. What is python's role here? You could execute it as a child process but then should python be filling in the prompts or should python let the user fill in the prompts? Do you just want the core of the algorithm and have python do most of the stuff in the example?

Comment: I'm trying to write the code such that C++ does everything apart from the post-processing and visualisation to be done in Python.

Comment: You say _"returns an integer value"_ but your code returns a possible large _"solution vector"_ which is a very different beast. You have many options but its kinda difficult to integrate a program that wants to do its own interaction with the user. It needs `stdin` and `stdout` so its difficult to load as a module for cython or ctypes to call or to run as a subprocess. It would be easier if you moved the prompts to python, had the C++ program accept command line output and had it write only the final output to stdout. Python could then call it and read its stdout to get data.

Comment: Ok, I've removed some of the clutter in the C++ code. Is my implementation of accepting input into the main function correct? How would I input these parameters and call this .cpp in Python? How would I output **U_Next** at every iteration of the for loop to Python as a vector?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html to see if it matches your needs. The module allows you to spawn new processes, so if you have the cpp source compiled you can just call the executable and process the output as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a .cpp file, as you need to compile a binary from your .cpp file before you can execute it. first, try to compile it using your terminal, after that you might port it to python, and automate it in a Python script (I guess, that's why you want to do it in Python).